# Initialize LibGDX without opening window

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a very straightforward question; is there a way to initialize LibGDX (as in, setting all of the static `Gdx.*` variables. If it helps I don't need the GL or AL context) without opening a window / canvas to go with it?

Perhaps there's an alternative to a `LwjglApplication`? I looked around and found some alternatives like `LwjglFrame` but those don't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: How can there be a GL context without a window? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I actually misspoke there, what I *don't* need is the GL and AL contexts since this process is just a server & console that's run directly from a .bat file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Headless classes in the [libGDX github repository](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/headless).